# How insert a list as a column in MySQL with Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7, list

So basically I have this list :

```
L1 = ['hel-lo', 'world123', 'bye', 'python']
```

I want to insert this list in my MySQL table, as follow :

```
+-------------------------+
|          words          |
+-------------------------+
| hel-lo                  |
| world123                |
| bye                     |
| python                  |
+-------------------------+
```

In reality, my list is composed of about 1000 elements. 
I tried many things which I found on StackOverflow, but nothing is working. (It seems that the elements are trying to be insert with this format  "['string']").

Last solution I tried :

```
values = [list([item]) for item in L1]
cursor.executemany(u"INSERT INTO `table`(`data`) VALUES %s", values)
```

Which returns this error :

```
 mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''hel-lo')' at line 1
```

Any advices are welcomed !

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Comment: I already saw this link, what I am messing ?

Comment: Why you have in the table `world123` and not `world` ?

Comment: @DavidWinder my mistake sorry

Comment: @DavidWinder Does it matter?

Comment: Doesn't matter but seem weird...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing parentheses around the value list in the query (should be `VALUES (%s)`). Also, `list([item])` can be simplified to just `[item]`:

```
L1 = ['hel-lo', 'world', 'bye', 'python']
values = [[item] for item in L1]
cursor.executemany(u"INSERT INTO `instability`(`ap_name`) VALUES (%s)", values)
```

Comment: Shame on me, I just noticed that I wrote " % " instead of "(%)". I have no error now but nothing is inserted is the DB

Comment: You may need to [commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) the transaction.